# Find sublists in a list by contents, then union them

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

I want to find two sublists in a list by an element they contain, and then union them, keeping them in the list.

I have this code that seems to do the job, but it seems rather clunky. Is there a better way to do it?

It finds the sublists from the example list 'groups' containing b and g, then unions them. You have to do the check to verify that the elements don't belong to the same sub-list already, or else you end up deleting the sub-list they're both contained in.

The master list will always be two levels deep, and wouldn't have any duplicates.

```
groups = {{a}, {b, c}, {d}, {e, f, g}}
firstPart = b;
secondPart = g;
fPAddress = Part[Position[groups, firstPart, 2], 1, 1];
sPAddress = Part[Position[groups, secondPart, 2], 1, 1];
If[fPAddress != sPAddress,
 groups = ReplacePart[groups, fPAddress ->
    Union[
     Part[groups, fPAddress],
     Part[groups, sPAddress]
     ]
   ];
 groups = Delete[groups, sPAddress];
 ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using rules:

```
groups //. {a___, x : {___, b | g, ___}, b___, y : {___, b | g, ___}, c___} :>
{a, Union[x, y], b, c}
```

This behaves differently compared to your code when there are more than two sublists which contain either `b` or `g`, in that it will take the union of all of them whereas your code doesn't do that. I hope this is what you intended, or perhaps it's never the case that there are more than two sublists involved?

Or, inspired by march's solution, we might also write

```
{hasNot, has} = GatherBy[groups, MemberQ[b | g]];
Append[hasNot, Union @@ has]
```

which can also be written

```
Append[#, Union @@ #2] & @@ GatherBy[groups, MemberQ[b | g]]
```

`MemberQ` can be replaced by `ContainsAny`. If performance is important, one might try this.

Comment: Yes, they work as intended, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

```
Flatten /@ Gather[groups, MemberQ[#1, b | g] && MemberQ[#2, b | g] &]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[conditionalUnion]
conditionalUnion[test_] := Reap[
   If[test @ #, 
      Sow[#, Apply @ Union], 
      Sow[#, Apply @ Sequence]] & /@ #,
    _, Construct][[2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
conditionalUnion[MatchQ[{___, b | g, ___}]] @ groups
```

> {{a}, {d}, {b, c, e, f, g}}

```
conditionalUnion[ContainsAny[{b, g}]] @ groups
```

> {{a}, {d}, {b, c, e, f, g}}

Take the union of sublists with lengths less than 3:

```
conditionalUnion[Length[#] <= 2&] @ groups
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}}

Comment: (+1) I really like this approach with `Reap` and `Sow` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
groups = {{a}, {b, c}, {d}, {e, f, g}};
```

Using `GroupBy`

```
{#[False], Union @@ #[True]}& @ GroupBy[groups, ContainsAny @ {b, g}]
```

{{{a}, {d}}, {b, c, e, f, g}}

```
{#[False], Union @@ #[True]}& @ GroupBy[groups, ContainsAny @ {a, g}]
```

{{{b, c}, {d}}, {a, e, f, g}}

Comment: Hi, @eldo! You can add `If[MatrixQ[#], Splice@#, #] &` in the third argument of `GroupBy` to get the solution in the form `{{a}, {d}, {b, c, e, f, g} }` :-)

Comment: Do you mean `GroupBy[groups, ContainsAny@{b, g}, If[MatrixQ[#], #, Splice@#] &]` ? - That doesn't seem to function,

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
groups = {{a}, {b, c}, {d}, {e, f, g}};

{hasNot, has} = {s_ /; ! ContainsAny[s, {b, g}] :> s, 
                 s_ /; ContainsAny[s, {b, g}] :> Splice@s};

ReplaceAll[m_ /; MatrixQ[m] :> Splice@m][Cases[groups, #] & /@ {hasNot, has}]

(*{{a}, {d}, {b, c, e, f, g}}*)
```